# How can I view all device names on LAN?

Tags: lan, nmap

I am trying to scan my local network and return a list of all connected devices with there IP, MAC Address & device name.

by device name I mean if it is my iPhone it would say 'Jamies-iPhone' as it would when I check my routers admin application for connected devices.

At the moment I have got as far as getting the IP and MAC using:

```
sudo nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -sP > file1.txt
```

It gives me the below output into the file 'file1.txt'

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-01 18:37 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
MAC Address: 8C:34:FD:E2:E6:48 (Unknown)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.3
Host is up (0.0038s latency).
MAC Address: 70:56:82:C6:BE:EE (Apple)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.10
Host is up (0.18s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 6.42 seconds
```

but I can not find any information about how to get the device name to show up, it just says 'Apple'. I specifically want to see the name of my apple TV's as I have a few and would like to be able to differentiate between them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get device name from scan like nmap on Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/702309/how-to-get-device-name-from-scan-like-nmap-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

The "Apple" listed there is [derived from the MAC address](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/) (it's in the range assigned to Apple).  NMap doesn't know if it's *actually* an Apple device.

If the device doesn't reply to a service with its name (that your utility also scans for), and it hasn't been registered in a local name service (like DNS; either manually, or registered by DHCP), then you can't know its name.

Comment: I now understand that the MAC address is within the range assigned to Apple as a company, which is why it says apple. If what your saying is correct then why can apple device names be seen by applications on other devices like phones or computers. For instance If I am connected to LAN with my phone or laptop I can see the names of all apple tv's on LAN just by looking at airplay options. This surely means it must be possible for any device to see the names of these apple tv's just by being connected to LAN?

Comment: It's because they're using a protocol nmap isn't configured to scan for. :)